# Proving results about complete Boolean algebras in ZFC using Boolean valued models

Tags: set-theory, big-list, forcing, boolean-algebras

I want to know what non-trivial ZFC theorems (not consistency results) about complete Boolean algebras (or more generally of partially ordered sets) one can prove using forcing. 
I am mainly interested in proofs of combinatorial properties of complete Boolean algebras such as the many [cardinal invariants on Boolean algebras](http://cardinal%20invariants%20on%20Boolean%20algebras). The proofs of results that I have in mind have the following form.

$\bullet$ One translates combinatorial properties of complete Boolean algebras $B$ to properties of the Boolean valued models $V^{B}$.

$\bullet$ One proves things about the Boolean valued models $V^{B}$.

$\bullet$ One translates the results about the Boolean valued models $V^{B}$ back to results about the complete Boolean algebras $B$.

I am interested in proofs of results where the only known proof uses forcing or where the proof without forcing is more difficult or at least equally difficult.

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/42569/22277) and [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/29945/22277) ask about ZFC results that can be proven using forcing, but now I am only asking about combinatorial results about complete Boolean algebras proven using forcing using the strategy mentioned above.

Comment: Don't all the ZFC theorems proved via forcing fit your Boolean-valued model paradigm? If not, could you clarify why not and what you want exactly?

Comment: Joel David Hamkins. I clarified that I want to know about combinatorial results on complete Boolean algebras.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me say a few such examples:

**1) (Kripke's theorem):** For every Boolean lagebra $B$, there is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that $B$ can be embedded in the collapsing algebra $Col(\aleph_0, \kappa).$

**2) (Solovay's theorem):** Let $B$ be a Souslin algebra. Then $|B|\leq 2^{\aleph_1}$ (see Jech 1978, Theorem 60, page 274).

In fact most of section 25 ``Forcing and complete Boolean algebras'' of Jech 1978, gives such examples.

**3) (Jensen's theorem):** Let $\kappa$ be an inaccessible cardinals and let $B=RO(P),$ where $P=Col(\aleph_0, < \kappa).$ If $B_1, B_2$ are complete Boolean algebras of size $<\kappa$ such that $B_1$ is a sub-algebra  of both $B$ and $B_1$, then there is an embedding $h$ of $B_2$ into $B$ such that $h\restriction B_1$ is the identity.

Comment: I don't have my copy of Jech's book handy, so the following might be in the section you cited, but if not then it could be added here: There is no free complete Boolean algebra on a countably infinite set of generators.

Answer (score 4):

You can, for example, show that many standard complete boolean algebras like Cohen algebra cannot be isomorphic to a quotient $\mathcal{P}(X) / I$ for any sigma ideal $I$ over $X$. These results are due to Gitik and Shelah and their proofs use generic ultrapowers.